# Can you hint return types in PHP 5.2.5?

Tags: php, eclipse, return-value, php-5.2, type-hinting

I think my eclipse's ctrl+clicking links might benefit greatly...

**Edit:** I'm using eclipse PDT.

**Edit 2:** I'm very happy with the solution of putting docblocks before functions (and variables) with an @return or @var statement, I've just updated the documentation of my app and now eclipse is showing me what functions are available to what objects!

Awesome.

Comment: Off topic, I've noticed that NetBeans 6.5 is a lot smarter with code completion and overall code analysis than the Eclipse PHP-aware stuff I've tried

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/778564/phpdoc-type-hinting-for-array-of-objects

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
// [...]
/**
 * Return the Request object
 *
 * @return Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract
 */
public function getRequest()
{
    return $this->_request;
}
// [...]
```

works perfectly with Eclipse PDT. Which plugin do you use?

Comment: How do you define the type of objects inside a returned array?

Comment: I don't think that's possible with current Eclipse PDT or Netbeans.

Comment: As far as I know at least the PDT team is looking at this issue.

Answer (score 5):

Short answer: no.

Long answer: consider adding docblocks with @return declarations.

Comment: It works for me. What eclipse plugin are you using for php development?

Comment: Strange, after some time it did work. But I didn't see a "building" status bar at the bottom or anything like that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The only way to hint return type in PHP is to use a good IDE like Eclispe PDT or Zend Studio with standard comment block. PHP simply can n not predict return type because it is dynamically typed language so type checking is done in the run time unlike for the statically typed languages like C#, JAVA and C++.