# how do i use @var on a function variable?

Tags: php, netbeans

i've got a variable $user that is of data type User (a class).

i've got it in a class method so i can't just type:

```
/**
 * @var User
 */
$user = Factory::getInstance('User');
```

because that will work only with class properties, not method variables like in this case.

how could i tell netbeans that that variable is of data type User in a method?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/778564/phpdoc-type-hinting-for-array-of-objects#778787), you can do this:

```
$user = Factory::getInstance('User');
/* @var $user User */

//netbeans should now autocomplete $user->
```