# How do I properly document an array property in a class for phpdocumentor?

Tags: php, phpdoc

I'm trying to find out how to properly document an array property in a class for phpdocumentor.

Ex:

```
<?php
class foo {
   /**
    * This holds something important
    * @var string
    */
    protected $junk;
   /**
    * This holds an important array of strings
    * @var ???????
    */
    protected $stuff = array();
    // ...
}
?>
```

I couldn't find anything in the phpdoc manual about array properties.

Comment: Have you tried `* @var string[]` ? See as well: [PHPDoc type hinting for array of objects?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/778564/367456)

Comment: In netbeans, it seems to accept the @var string[].  Thanks

Comment: But you have asked for PHPDocumentor, not Netbeans.

Comment: Well, there are about 30 properties in the parent class and only one is an array.  In the multiple classes extending the parent I can quickly see what I'm dealing with.

Comment: I'm hoping it will work with both.. will let you know soon if PHPDocuemntor accepts this

Comment: What additional features do you get when typing a property as an array with neatbeans? Since arrays in PHP aren't objects you don't get any autocomplete. What do you mean if PHPDoc accepts it? `array` is the official data-type of PHP. `gettype()` returns `array` not `string[]`

Comment: Mike, after some reading, you are correct: @var array is what is suggested in Zandstra's OOP PHP book, and it works.  However, "array" was NOT listed as an option in the documentation for PHPDocumentor.  What I meant by "accept" is whether or not PHPDocumentor would successfully parse my comments and turn them into an HTML version without throwing errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`/** @var array */` for your `protected $stuff` is the proper syntax.  The phpDocumentor manual page for @var shows "The datatype should be a valid PHP type (int, string, bool, etc),", and "array" is such a valid PHP type.

Some IDEs have also begun recognizing `/** @var ElementType[] */` to indicate "this is an array, whose elements are all of type ElementType".  This syntax will be available in an upcoming version of phpDocumentor.