# How can I specify array of objects in PhpDoc

Tags: php, phpdoc

I use PhpDocumentor2 for generating documentation.
I searched for this subject but I can't find specific rule for it.
For Example I have class which name is AddressField and I want to specify my $addressFields as array of AddressField objects.

```
/**
 * @var AddressField[]
 */
private $addressFields;
```

Comment: @Jack I examined this question but I can't find answer to my question

Comment: If this [Eclipse thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/778564/phpdoc-type-hinting-for-array-of-objects) is to be believed, your syntax should work in future :)

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, the format you show above is correct. Its just not widely supported. I do know that PHPStorm uses that format at least.

Comment: @Jack I'm from the future and I can confirm your comment. It works nowadays.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

*phpdoc* themselves describe the use of arrays **[here](https://docs.phpdoc.org/guide/guides/types.html#arrays)**:

> #### 1.4.4. Arrays
>
> - undefined: `@return array`
> - single type: `@return int[]`
> - multi type: `@return (int|string)[]`

The same should apply to variable definitions:

```
/* @var Type[] $arr */
```

Comment: You may also write `int[]|string[]`

Comment: There is also a proposed PSR: [PSR-5: PHPDoc on Arrays](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/proposed/phpdoc.md#arrays)