# Code hinting by parameters

Tags: php, eclipse, zend-framework

is it possible to get code hinting if you have a parameter of array of objects.

This works:

```
/**
 * @return MyObject[]
 */
public function moo() {
   return array(new MyObject(), new MyObject());
}

public function bla() {
  foreach ($this->moo() as $obj) {
     $obj->IGetCodeHintingHere(); 
  }
}
```

Is the same way possible with @param like @return?
For example like this:

```
/**
 * @param $MyObject[]
 */
public function bla(array $aaa) {
  foreach ($aaa as $a) {
     $a->IWantGetCodeHintingHereToo(); 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possible duplicate of:

[PHPDoc type hinting for array of objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/778564/phpdoc-type-hinting-for-array-of-objects)

and

[How can I specify array of objects in PhpDoc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13455473/how-can-i-specify-array-of-objects-in-phpdoc)

To give you an answer, you can see and try if your IDE supports this doc syntax:

```
/**
 * @param $aaa MyObject[]
 */
public function bla(array $aaa) {
  foreach ($aaa as $a) {
     $a->IWantGetCodeHintingHereToo(); 
  }
}
```

Good luck and have fun!