# Netbeans method params typehinting with array of objects - code completion

Tags: php, netbeans

I'm having a little problem with Netbeans and code completion.
Here is a straightforward example :

```
/**
* @param SomeClass[] $param Simple array of SomeClass elements
*/
public function func(array $param) {
    $param[0]->..
}
```

In this sample, the code completion does not work. The problem comes from the `array $param` which "overwrite" the phpdoc declaration and thus i don't have code completion for my class anymore.

Is this a bug or made i a mistake ?

Answer (score 1):

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/778564/phpdoc-type-hinting-for-array-of-objects), the following should work in Netbeans:

```
public function func(array $param) {
    /* @var $param SomeClass[] */
    $param[0]->..
}
```

Comment: Yeah i'm aware of this, but i expected a normal behaviour from netbeans. I'm wondering if i should report this to netbeans makers.