# Hint iterator of strict type entities in PHPDoc

Tags: php, phpdoc

**Specifics**

- I am using PHPStorm 8 IDE.
- Let's assume we have some class `Foo` which implements [`\Iterator`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.iterator.php) interface and we know that all items inside that iterator will be of instance of class `Bar`.

**Question**

How to hint that `Foo` is iterable and contains only items of `Bar`? Of course, hint should keep information, that it's instance of `Foo`

**What I tried so far**

If we had an array of `Bar` instances, then that is an easy thing (it's described, for instance, in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/778564/phpdoc-type-hinting-for-array-of-objects) question): `Bar[]`. Also, if the intention is to iterate through `Foo`, it still can be resolved (more or less) with:

```
//assume that $foo is instance of Foo
//..
 
/* @var $object Bar */
foreach ($foo as $object) {
}
```

However, there is one very important thing which is not achievable with in-place hinting: return type. If I'll have some method which should return `Foo`, I know only how to hint that `Foo`, but user of that function still won't be able to expose, that it's actually iterable and contains `Bar` instances (like it would be if I'll specify `@return Bar[]` in case with array of `Bar` instances)

Answer (score 4):

If `Foo` implements `Iterator` then you can hint the return type on `Foo::current()`. PHPStorm will recognise that what `Foo::current()` returns is the value when you `foreach` over `Foo`.

For example:

```
<?php

class Foo implements Iterator
{
    // ...

    /**
     * @return Bar
     */
    public function current()
    {
        // ...
    }

    // ...
}

$foo = new Foo();

foreach ($foo as $object) {
    // PHPStorm will recognise $object is type Bar.
}
```