# phpdoc @return value for PHPUnit dataProvider

Tags: phpunit, phpdoc

Is there a phpdoc-compliant way* of expressing the various returned values in a PHPUnit dataProvider?

For example:

```
return array(
    array(false, 17, array(1,2)),
    array(true, 19, array(1,2)),
);
```

I would like to write something more detailed than `@return array`, that expresses that the first value passed to the test method is a bool, the second is an integer, third is an array (and also what each of these values represent).

* If there's no compliant way, does anyone have tips on how to document in a clear manner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only further specification for arrays is what they contain (if always the same type):

```
/**
 * @return array[]
 */
function() {
    // ...
}
```

This annotation expresses the function will return an array of arrays, you can find a further discussion in this question:

[PHPDoc type hinting for array of objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/778564/phpdoc-type-hinting-for-array-of-objects)

**Note:** Not every IDE will be able to interpret it

To a possible clear manner: In my opinion, you can always use code blocks in your comments to explain some of your code:

```
/**
 * returns array with following structure:
 * <code>
 * array(
 *     array(
 *         (bool), (int), (array)
 *     )
 * )
 * </code>
 *
 * @return array[]
 */
```

Or similar explanation. I'm sure there are plenty ways to give other developers a hint about what to expect. In the end it just needs to be understandable to a human if it is not included in the usual annotations.