# php foreach object hint

Tags: php, object, foreach

```
foreach ($results as $obj) {
    $this->dates[$obj->getName()] = $obj;
}
```

This runs fine, but PHPStorm gives the hint,

> Method getName not found in class.

Seems like there ought to be a way to give it a hint about the type of the object. How do I get it to recognize that this is an instance of a particular class like we can with method parameters? Something like

```
foreach ($results as MyClass $obj) {
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHPDoc type hinting for array of objects?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/778564/phpdoc-type-hinting-for-array-of-objects)

Comment: Thanks, that worked.

Comment: @Matei Thanks, that worked. The OP had a different question, but the answer to mine was included in the answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key is not adding the Doc hint above or a type hint inside the foreach like 
I tried, but below the line, inside the code block.

```
   foreach ($results as $obj) {
        /* @var $obj MyClass */
        $this->dates[$obj->getName()] = $obj;
   }
```