# Getting the child-type of an object from a method inherited from the father

Tags: php, oop, inheritance, types, ide

my problem is getting the right type of object from a method, which is returning a "mixed" type due to inhreitance.

I've got a generic list class

```
class List
{
    /**
    * @var Item[]
    */
    protected $items;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->items = array();
    }

    /**
    * @return Item[]
    */
    public function getAll()
    {
        return $this->items;
    }


    /**
    * @return Item
    */
    public function getOne($index)
    {
        if (isset($this->items[$index])) {
            return $this->items[$index];
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

containing element of type Item, which is a generic class either

```
class Item
{
    /**
    * @var string
    */
    protected $name;

    public function __construct($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
    }
}
```

Such generic classes are extended by N different lists. Just an example

```
class UserList extends List
{
    /* user-specific implementation */
}

class User extends Item
{
    /* user-specific implementation */
}
```

In the client code

```
$user_list = new UserList();
foreach ($user_list->getAll() as $user) {
    echo $user->getEmailAddr();
}
```

Inside the foreach I don't have code completion, because my getAll method (inherited from the father) is returning Item[], or mixed[], not a User[]. Same problem with getOne method.
I wouldn't like to have to override such methods.

Is there a more clever and elegant solution?
Thank you

Comment: Most IDEs will provide a way for you to help them by telling it what type is used in the iteration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's any way for the IDE to infer the type automatically. Use a phpdoc type annotation:

```
foreach ($user_list->getAll() as $user) {
    /** @var User $user */
    echo $user->getEmailAddr();
}
```

See the related question [PHPDoc type hinting for array of objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/778564/phpdoc-type-hinting-for-array-of-objects)

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot