# PhpStorm warns about “Expected Class, got Class[]”

Tags: php, phpstorm

As I know I can't define array of class as function argument.

Like:

```php
someFunc(someClass[] $some) {}
```

But I get PhpStorm warning about wrong argument when pass the array of class items. Can someone explain to me this warning?

Example of my code:

```php
public function getContent(Item $item)
{
   ...
}

// $items is items array of class Item
$content = getContent($items)
```

Comment: php is not java. this topic is now and then discussed by the php developers as far as I know. But not yet implemented

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/778564/phpdoc-type-hinting-for-array-of-objects

Comment: It isn't a PhpStorm issue. The code [triggers a fatal error when you run it](https://3v4l.org/00ups) since types don't match.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PhpStorm understands [phpDoc](https://docs.phpdoc.org/guides/types.html) tags.

So you can do something like this:

```
/**
 * @param Item[] $item The item to get the content from.
 */
public function getContent(array $item)
{
   ...
}
```

But you **must** use `array` in code since that's what the type is. But PhpStorm will also understand your phpDoc annotation to provide better hints as you type.